# Help calculating integral over a region $G$ with spherical coordinates?

Tags: multiple-integral

So i have to calculate this triple integral:

$$\iiint_GzdV$$
Where G is defined as: $$x^2+y^2-z^2 \geq 6R^2, x^2+y^2+z^2\leq12R^2, z\geq0$$

So with drawing it it gives this:

[image: G region]

It seems i should use spherical coordinates since sphere is involved.
But i don't know if i can use the default ones or should manipulate them since i have hyperbole of some sort(but since its $a=b=c$, is it a double sided cone then? i know that z>0 means im only looking at upper half, but still)

So using this:

$$x=r\cos\phi\cos\theta; y=r\sin\phi\cos\theta ; z=r\sin\theta$$

So i think $$\phi \in [0,2\pi]$$
And for $$r: r^2\leq12R^2$$
But am not sure about theta, how can i get it?
From the $z\geq0$ i get $r\sin\theta>=0$  so $\sin\theta \geq 0$
So from that is $0\leq\theta\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Am I doing it correctly, or should i fix anything,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition
$$
x^2+y^2-z^2\geq 6R^2
$$
gives
$$
r^2(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)\geq 6R^2
$$
So you want $(r,\theta)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,\frac\pi2)$ such that
$$
r^2\leq 12R^2 \text{ and } r^2(1-\cos 2\theta)\geq 6R^2
$$
So $1-\cos 2\theta\geq\frac12$, i.e, $\cos 2\theta\leq \frac12$ and hence $\theta\in(0,\frac\pi6)$.  Putting them together,
$$
\\\int_G z\,\mathrm{d}V=
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/6}\int_{R\sqrt{6/(1-\cos 2\theta)}}^{R\sqrt{12}} r\cos\theta\,r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi
$$

Comment: +1 It seems you left out the $\mathrm{dr}$ in the integral, though.

Comment: oops, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to calculate the following *triple integral*:
$$I := \iiint\limits_{\Omega} z\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z$$
with:
$$\Omega := \left\{ (x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \ge 6R^2 + z^2, \; x^2 +y^2 + z^2 \le 12R^2, \; z \ge 0 \; ; \; R > 0 \right\},$$
opting for a *transformation* from rectangular to polar coordinates, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho^2\,\sin^2\varphi \ge 6R^2 + \rho^2\,\cos^2\varphi \\
\rho^2 \le 12R^2 \\
\rho\,\cos\varphi \ge 0 \\
\rho \ge 0 \\
0 \le \varphi \le \pi \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \Leftrightarrow \; \; \; \; \; \;
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{\frac{6}{-\cos(2\varphi)}}\,R \le \rho \le 2\sqrt{3}\,R \\
\frac{\pi}{3} \le \varphi \le \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$
from which:
$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d}\theta \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(2\varphi)}{2}\,\text{d}\varphi \int_{\sqrt{\frac{6}{-\cos(2\varphi)}}\,R}^{2\sqrt{3}\,R} \rho^3\,\text{d}\rho = \frac{9}{2}\,\pi\,R^4\,, $$
while opting for a *transformation* from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
\rho^2 \ge t^2 + 6R^2 \\
\rho^2 + t^2 \le 12R^2 \\
t \ge 0 \\
\rho \ge 0 \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi
\end{cases}
\; \; \; \; \; \; \Leftrightarrow \; \; \; \; \; \;
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{6R^2 + t^2} \le \rho \le \sqrt{12R^2 - t^2} \\
0 \le \theta < 2\pi \\
0 \le t \le \sqrt{3}\,R
\end{cases}
$$
from which:
$$I = \int_0^{\sqrt{3}\,R} t\,\text{d}t \int_0^{2\pi} \text{d}\theta \int_{\sqrt{6R^2 + t^2}}^{\sqrt{12R^2 - t^2}} \rho\,\text{d}\rho = \frac{9}{2}\,\pi\,R^4\,.$$
Since $\Omega$ has a cylindrical and non polar symmetry, it is clear that the second way is less calculative.